# Issue with show hide jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

`$('#estimate').show();` is working after api call is completed, but I need to achieve before api call.

Style apply after api call completion, Is there is any alternate way to do this?

If response takes 3 sec div is showing after 3 sec brfore itself need to show that div

```js
var formdata = {
  "latlon1": "80.2707,13.0827",
  "latlon2": "78.7047,10.7905"
}
 $("#dSedan,#dSuv,#dInnova,#dSuvR,#dSedanR").on('click', function ()  {           $('#estimate').show();
  $("#estdistancedt").empty()
  $(".estdtbreakup").html("")
  $("#estimate .estamount").html("<img src='images/loading.gif' />");
                getestimate(formData);
        })



function getestimate(formdata) {
 
  if (formdata.latlon1 && formdata.latlon2) {
    console.log(formdata);

    var settings = {
      "url": serverurl + "rest/estimatecalculate",
      "method": "POST",
      "timeout": 0,
      'dataType': "json",
      "crossDomain": true,
      "headers": {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
      },
      "data": JSON.stringify(formdata),
    };
    $.ajax(settings).done(function(element) {
      $("#estdistancedt").empty().append("Distance:" + element.distance.toFixed() + " kms");
      $(".estamount").html(element.estimate);
      $(".estdtbreakup").html("[Base charges: &#8377; " + element.basecharge + " / Driver bata: &#8377; " + element.driverbata);
      if (element.isp != 0) {
        $(".estdtbreakup").append(" / ISP: &#8377; " + element.isp);
      }
      if (element.hillcharges != 0) {
        $(".estdtbreakup").append(" / Hill charges: &#8377; " + element.hillcharges);
      }
      $(".estdtbreakup").append(" + Toll at actuals]");
      $(".tripamount").val(element.estimate)
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Add this `$('#estimate').show();` in .done(function (element) {}); remove from after function

Answer (score 0):

please add a button and after that call your code like this

`<button id="yourID">Submit</button>`

```
var formdata = {
    "latlon1": "80.2707,13.0827",
    "latlon2": "78.7047,10.7905"
}

$(document).on('click', '#yourID', function(event) {
   $('#estimate').show(); // YOUR DIV SHOW ON CLICK 
   $('.spiner').show(); // IF YOU WANT TO ADD SPINER
   getestimate(formdata);
});
```

and remove `$('#estimate').show();` from function

```
function getestimate(formdata){
        // $('#estimate').show(); // REMOVE THIS LINE
        $("#estdistancedt").empty()
        $(".estdtbreakup").html("")
        $("#estimate .estamount").html("<img src='images/loading.gif' />");
    if(formdata.latlon1&&formdata.latlon2){
        console.log(formdata);
        
            var settings = {
                "url": serverurl+"rest/estimatecalculate",
                "method": "POST",
                "timeout": 0,
                'dataType': "json",
                "crossDomain": true,
                "headers": {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json",
                    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
                },
                "data": JSON.stringify(formdata),
            };
            $.ajax(settings).done(function (element) {
                $("#estdistancedt").empty().append("Distance:" + element.distance.toFixed() + " kms");
                $(".estamount").html(element.estimate);
                $(".estdtbreakup").html("[Base charges: &#8377; " + element.basecharge + " / Driver bata: &#8377; " + element.driverbata);
                if (element.isp != 0) {
                    $(".estdtbreakup").append(" / ISP: &#8377; " + element.isp);
                }
                if (element.hillcharges != 0) {
                    $(".estdtbreakup").append(" / Hill charges: &#8377; " + element.hillcharges);
                }
                $(".estdtbreakup").append(" + Toll at actuals]");
                $(".tripamount").val(element.estimate)
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi Hiren I have tried like that only calling function after click event but still its waiting

Comment: please check I edit the post comment and try again

*$(document).on('submit', '#yourID', function(event) {* To 

*$(document).on('click', '#yourID', function(event) {*